# Efficiently rendering many images on a unified canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm lost and in need of direction.

We're trying to render a bunch of small images (X) onto a single, unified canvas using imagemagick.

The different X's can be one of five different sizes: 20x20, 40x40, 60x60, 80x80 or 100x100 each. The large image's width is always set to 600, but the height can be regulated as needed.

We can be using as few as 10 or as many as 10,000 X's at any given moment.

Currently, the bare-bones proof of concept we're working with goes something like:

```
images.each do |image|

      image = Magick::Image.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/#{image}").first

      w = image.columns
      h = image.rows

      pixels = image.export_pixels(0, 0, w, h, "RGB")

      img.import_pixels(x, y, w, h, "RGB", pixels)

      x += w

end
```

...it's simple and stupid, but it does output a series of images merged into one. Almost there  ;-)

Does anyone know of an effective algorithm with which we can iterate many X's and place them side-by-side, spanning multiple lines and still optimizing the space? **The goal here is to create a single image without white space, constructed by all small images.**

As stated, I would love any feedback you guys might have on this. Pointers? Ideas? Examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like right now the images are noise. You want to solve a tiles problem. The tiles have some fixed size and you want to put them on a surface of a fixed width and minimum height. This can be done globally with DFS, BFS, A*, etc. You can also look at some local method like simulated annealing or hill climbing, depending if you need to global optimum or just a good, reasonable solution. You can find implementations of these methods in the [online source repository for AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/code.html).

Once you have solved the tile problem you can overlay the images, with as piece of code similar to the one you're showing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply carlosdc! I've been spending the morning trying to find reference implementations of the methods you mention to no avail. Do you have something in mind? Thanks again.